# Trying to create new Laravel project but I get this error

Tags: php, laravel, curl, composer-php

It worked fine, but after I installed the cURL in my machine (Windows10), I started to deal with this issue every time I tried to create a Laravel project.

```
 Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/framework[v9.36.4, ..., 9.x-dev] require league/flysystem ^3.8.0 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[3.8.0, ..., 3.x-dev].
    - laravel/framework[v9.19.0, ..., v9.36.3] require league/flysystem ^3.0.16 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[3.0.16, ..., 3.x-dev].
    - league/flysystem[3.0.16, ..., 3.x-dev] require league/mime-type-detection ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable by league/mime-type-detection[1.0.0, ..., 1.11.0].
    - league/mime-type-detection[1.0.0, ..., 1.3.0] require php ^7.2 -> your php version (8.1.12) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - league/mime-type-detection[1.4.0, ..., 1.11.0] require ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^9.19 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v9.19.0, ..., 9.x-dev].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\Program Files\php-8.1.12\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-fileinfo` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.
```

I Tried to uncomment this command 'extension=openssl' in php.ini
I also executed this command 'composer config -g -- disable-tls false' but nothing has changed .

Comment: "league/mime-type-detection[1.0.0, ..., 1.3.0] require php ^7.2 -> your php version (8.1.12) does not satisfy that requirement."


This line is highlighting the source of the issue: it seems you've upgraded your PHP version, and now it complains on "league/mime-type-detection" requiring a lower PHP version (around 7.2) than you have (8.1).


What is the exact command you use to create a new laravel project?

Comment: 'composer global require laravel/installer' then 'laravel new Project'

Comment: Since you are on PHP 8, try this command instead: `composer create-project laravel/laravel:9.* your-directory-name`

Comment: `league/mime-type-detection[1.4.0, ..., 1.11.0] require ext-fileinfo` - did you even try to resolve this in any way? It looks obvious to me that enabling the openssl extension does not resolve this, as this isn't even mentioned in the error